# Neo4j recursion in Java classes

Tags: java, database, neo4j, backend

I am developing a project using relational and non relational database. I would like to know if there is recursion to create the nodes in Neo4j. The backend is developed in Java and I did not find any information that could help me. I need this recursion in the non relational bank.
[Example of recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIJsL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have a node have a relationship to itself :

```
CREATE (p:Person {name:"Tom"})
CREATE (p)-[:LIKES]->(p)
```

Comment: With Chyper I know how to do it, I wonder if I can do it using Java, because the back end is developed in Java.

Comment: Have you tried : node.createRelationshipTo(node, RelTypes.LIKES); ? That should work.